# fineuploader image uploads include caption with uploaded files

Tags: image, file-upload, fine-uploader, captions

I have a legacy app that has five separate file uploads for a single DB record. Beside each file upload there is a field to enter a caption for the uploaded file.

I am considering replacing the whole lot with a [fineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) gallery and allow up to ten files to be uploaded.

However, it was useful on the old system to have a caption with each image for the ALT tag of the image when it comes to web display.

I could address this with multiple single file uploads using fineuploader and a caption field for each but I want to get away from having so many on the page.

I see there is an option to change the file name during upload so that might be an option but that could lead to very long/messy file names and may cause issues with accents and other characters.

Can anyone suggest a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest considering you use the built-in edit filename feature, as this seems most appropriate to me and will certainly be the simplest approach.

Another approach involves the following:

1. Add a file input field to your Fine Uploader template. This will hold the user-entered caption value. You will likely need some CSS as well to make this look appropriate for your project.
2. Initialize Fine Uploader with the [`autoUpload` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#autoUpload) set to `false`. This will allow your users to enter in captions and then upload the files by clicking a button (to be added later).
3. Register an [`onUpload` callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#upload). Here, you will read the value of the associated file's caption stored in the text input and tie it to the file with the [`setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams).

The file list portion of [your template](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html) may look something like this:

```html
<ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
   <li>
      ...
      <input class="caption">
   </li>
</ul>
```

And your Fine Uploader code will contain this logic (important but unrelated options such as [`request.endpoint`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.endpoint) and [`element`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#element) left out to maintain focus on your question):

```js
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   autoUpload: false,
   callbacks: {
      onUpload: function(id) {
         var fileContainer = this.getItemByFileId(id)
         var captionInput = fileContainer.querySelector('.caption')
         var captionText = captionInput.value

         this.setParams({caption: captionText}, id)
      }
   }
})
```

Your server will receive a "caption" parameter with the associated value as part of each file's upload request.